# Fragment not showing in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with its own layout, and the activity in which the fragment should be added has this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <fragment
    android:name="com.myapp.MyFragment"
    android:id="@+id/myfragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/myfragment_layout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in the activity class:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

    fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.myfragment);
    if (fragment == null) {
        fragment = new MyFragment();

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.myfragment, fragment, "myfragment");
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

The onCreateView of the fragment is:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container, false);
}
```

But the fragment is not showing. No exception is thrown. The activity remains blank.

What am I missing?

Comment: Weights do not work in Relative layout. Try changing width of Fragment tag to something else.

Answer (score 5):

Replace the below lines

android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_width="0dp"

with

`android:layout_width="match_parent"` **or**     `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

because `RelativeLayout`  doesn't accept the layout_weight.

Comment: Correct. Copy and paste mistake!!

Comment: Ya. You have to either change the width as he mentioned above or change the RelativeLayout to LinearLayout