# Fragment is not shown with activity start

Tags: android, android-fragments

I implemented a bottom Navigation that should be filled with three different Fragment classes. 
My Problem is that if i start the activity the first Fragment layout is not shown, only if i go to tab2 and return to tab1.
I think it is a Problem with the LifeCycle but i have no idea how i can fix it.

my bottom Navigation class that handle the Navigation:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                fragment = new RequestFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                fragment = new ResponseFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                fragment = new LogfileFragment();
                break;
        }
        final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
        return true;
```

And my Fragment class:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_request, container, false);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragment not showing in activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30817665/fragment-not-showing-in-activity)

Comment: in the onCreate of the activity put your fragment transaction code for fragment 1, this is because onNavigationItemSelected is not called until you physically select a navigation item.

Comment: `onNavigationItemSelected` is called each time you "click" on a tab. When you first start your activity, no "click" has occurred in any tab, so no fragment is displayed. You have to manually initialize the first frament outside the `onNavigationItemSelected` method. Post more code if you need more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should add the first fragment  when activity start. you just set first fragment on onNavigationItemSelected() method and it never called even you click on navigation View. you should add these lines in onCreate() method:

```
fragment = new RequestFragment();
 final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the fragment inside onCreate() method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity);

    ...

    fragment = new RequestFragment();

    final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
}
```

This will display the fragment in the container inside the view when your activity starts. Keep your onNavigationItemSelected method as it is.